# Issues about grouping and appending div

Tags: javascript, html, css

**[EDIT]** I tried to dynamically create 6 horizontal lines every 1 second using setTimeout method. So it should shows every 6 horizontal lines as a group for every 1 second.  Here, I call 6 horizontal lines as group.  However, I want to append each group horizontally rather than vertically.  When trying to append a group and the width of the border is not long enough to hold a new group, append the new group to next lines.  And also  I want a "pilar" between each grounp of 6 horizontal lines, and I only want to create 8 group of horizontal lines. The first picture below is what I get after running my code.  The second one is what I need. The code below is my html, css, and js code.  Hope someone could help me out.  Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code_js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "output">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.deco {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 120px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    margin-right: 20px;
}


#output {
    background: #ffe6e6;
    width: 600px;
    height: 800px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    makeItHappen(0);
});

function makeItHappen(order) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        var hr = document.createElement('hr');
        hr.className = "deco"
        hr.id = "hr" + i;
        $('#output').append(hr);
    }
    makeTable(function() {
        if(++order < 7) {
            makeItHappen(order);
        }
    });
}

function makeTable(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback();
    }, 1000); 
}
```

Comment: why not just use a table instead of faking one?

Comment: why there is for loop to call 4 times settimeout ..So,do u mean you want 4 sets ,in each set 6 horizantal lines

Comment: @happymacarts Thank you replying.  The reason that I do not use table is because that in that way I cannot assign the id to the horizontal borders in the table

Comment: Agree with the above comment.. Also the for loop with a settimeout will create 4 times, all of which time out in ~1 second.. It this your intention? It seems rather strange.

Comment: @Geeky in makeTable(), I looped 6 times to create 6 horizontal lines.  In ready() method, I create 6 horizontal lines for every 1 sec and I only want to create 4 times in that case.  I know it might sounds weird to you, but this is what I need.

Comment: If you create a codepen or plunkr it is easier to help.

Comment: @Amonn sorry for the confusion.  I just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use display:flex to get the output you are expecting

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  makeItHappen(0);
});

function makeItHappen(order) {
  var output = $("#output");
  var div = $("<div></div>");
  div.attr('id', order);
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var hr = document.createElement('hr');
    hr.className = "deco"
    hr.id = "hr" + i;
    $(div).append(hr);
  }
  output.append(div);

  makeTable(function() {
    if (++order < 7) {
      makeItHappen(order);
    }
  });
}

function makeTable(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.deco {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#output div:nth-child(2n+1) {
  border-right: 5px solid green;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#output div:nth-child(2n) {
  border-right: 5px solid green;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: auto;
}
#output {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#output {
  background: #ffe6e6;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Hope it helps